# angular material 2 tabs scroll showing on navigation

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

As you can see in this example when you change tabs vertical scrollbar appears on animation.

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">
    <div style="height: 2000px">Content 1</div>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">
    <div style="height: 500px">Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Is it possible to remove that scrollbar (only on tab transition)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, set the `dynamicHeight` input to `true`.

```
<md-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="true">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">
    <div style="height: 2000px">Content 1</div>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">
    <div style="height: 500px">Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Working [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MM09y7hCM5Z7SA0LR3wF?p=preview)