# Vertical and horizontal Scrollbar appears for no reason in angular material 2

Tags: html, angular, css, angular-material2

I am trying to implement modal dialog that contains tabs using angular material 2.
But it is showing vertical and horizontal scroll bar for no reason. Can someone help in removing the vertical and horizontal scrollbar.

[image]

**Here is the stackblitz link**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialog-directives-demo-xnfx28?file=app%2Ffile-name-dialog.component.html

Comment: Can you please place part of the code that's causing the issue **in your question**? This makes it easier so that people don't have to click a link just to see your code. Also, **please don't use bold unnecessarily.**

Comment: Maybe try `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: The code is very large.So I thought of  writing entire code in stackblitz and referring the link here. So that you can the see the execution of how my code work

Comment: Try `[dynamicHeight]="true"`. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798581/angular-material-2-tabs-scroll-showing-on-navigation).

Comment: This is an open issue with angular materials. link here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/6104 . See if the work-around in the link works for you.

Answer (score 1):

it will work when you remove margin bottom from this class
.mat-dialog-actions:last-child {

```
/*   margin-bottom: -24px;   */
```

}
also you need to remove 
 margin: 0 -24px; from .mat-dialog-content class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
 overflow: hidden !important;
 }
```

For specific vertical and horizontal hide

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
            overflow-x: hidden !important;
            overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked to get rid of the vertical overflow:

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

::ng-deep .mat-dialog-actions {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I thing this issue caused by `mat-dialog-content` and `mat-dialog-actions` tags, when removing the tags it working fine, I think it need to change the styling property
to  overflow: hidden;